# What is the name of this sequence that approximates $\pi$?

Tags: summation, terminology, approximation, pi

I came across this sequence $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{2n\choose n}n^m=a_{m}+b_{m}\pi$$ where $a_m$ and $b_m$ are rational with $\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{a_m}{b_m}=\pi$. I cannot figure out where it comes from or if it has a name. Any ideas?

Comment: It also not clear to me how to approximate $\pi$ using the LHS.

Comment: Numerically, it seems to me like $\frac{a_m}{b_m}$ is always a continued fraction convergent to $\pi$.

Comment: Who is the person who wants to close this question ? Had you  the same question in mind, it is very likely that you have not a single idea of track of solution !

Comment: Not everything has a name.

Comment: @JeanMarie, it must be missing context or an explanation of its importance or the relevant definitions! You know, we are very picky. Maybe the problem is that the OP contains two different questions!

Comment: [See my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784843/closed-form-for-sm-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n-cdot-nm-binom2nn-f)

Answer (score 9):

Write it as $$S_m=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{2n\choose n}n^m=a_{m}+\frac \pi 2 \, b_{m}$$

The first $a_m$ are
$$\{1,3,11,55,355,2807,26259,283623,3473315,47552791,719718067\}$$ and this is sequence $A180875$ in $OEIS$.

Quoting $OEIS$, these are *"Lehmer's coefficients stemming from an inverse binomial coefficient series"*

The first $b_m$ are
$$\{1,2,7,35,226,1787,16717,180560,2211181,30273047,458186752\}$$ and this is sequence $A014307$ in $OEIS$.

If you look in the formula sections, you will find approximations given in year $2014$ by Vaclav Kotesovec, namely
$$a_m \sim \frac {\pi  m^{m+1} }{\sqrt{2} e^m \log ^{m+\frac{3}{2}}(2) }\qquad \qquad b_m\sim\frac{\sqrt{2} (m+1)^{m+1}}{e^{m+1} \log ^{m+\frac{3}{2}}(2) }$$

So, using these approximations
$$2\frac { a_m}  {b_m}\sim \pi \,e \,\left(\frac m {m+1} \right)^{m+1}$$ which is not good for an estimation of the error.

For $0 \leq m \leq 15$, a quick and dirty linear regression gives $(R^2=0.979)$ gives
$$\log \left(\left| 2\frac{ a_m}{b_m}-\pi \right| \right)=-2.14718 m-1.37498$$ Increasing the range of $m$ and searching for nice looking numbers in inverse symbolic calculators
$$\left| 2\frac{ a_m}{b_m}-\pi \right| \sim e^{-e/2} \left(\frac{\log (2)}{2 \pi }\right)^m$$

**Edit**

Formally, in terms of  the generalized hypergeometric function
$$S_m=\, _{(m+1)}F_m\left(2,\cdots,2;1,\cdots,1,\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: The validity of your last expansion depends on wheter the relative errors in Kotesovec's approximations are at most $\mathcal{O}(m^{-4})$. I assume they are not as it seems the Stirling formula was used in them to approximate factorials.

Comment: [A180875](https://oeis.org/A180875) is a clickable reference to the OEIS entry you mention. The LINKS section of the OEIS entry gives good sources.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Hi, Claude ! Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/85764/305862 with the reference in the comments to the paper "Lehmer's interesting series" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4274.pdf, the very same Lehmer you are quoting...

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thank you !

Comment: @JeanMarie. I added a second answer

Answer (score 8):

A little internet search led me to
[this page](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse11.php). Here someone plays a little around with some series represantion of trigfunctions using the central binomial coefficient:

$$ C = \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

Note: These are called central binomial coefficients because they form the central column in Pascal's triangle.

After some playful integration and other mathematical magic one can show by differentiating $u \frac{d}{du} \arcsin^2(\sqrt u)$ that:

$$\pi = -2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{n+1}}{C}$$

As far as I can tell the formula in question, i.e.

$$ \forall k\geq0, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^k \frac{2^n}{C} = a_k \pi + b_k, \text{where } \frac{b_k}{a_k} \rightarrow \pi$$

is this an open conjecture (Conjectur 16 [here](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse11.php)). I personally would assume the arrow stans for "as $k \rightarrow \infty$", yet i am not really sure. And apparently this conjecture stems from the mind of Géry Huvent, a french mathematician it seems to me. (Huvent on [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gery-Huvent-2))

Since his publications are written in french I personally know only very, very basic french, I wasn't able to find a publication which mentions this conjecture or how he had come up with it. But maybe someone more skilled in the french language can find such a paper...

Or his (I think) [personal webpage](http://gery.huvent.pagesperso-orange.fr/index_explorer_net.htm), which is sadly also in french, could be of assistance.

Comment: If you desire a translation of a part, I can do it.

Comment: Did Géry Huvent's page go somewhere else? His work should not be lost...

Answer (score 4):

*Too long for a comment.*

In comments, @JeanMarie gave a link to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85764/derive-a-closed-form-for-a-sum-with-inverse-binomial-coefficients) from @Felix Marin

$$S_1=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n\,x^{n} \over {2n \choose n}}=x\,\frac{6 \sqrt{(4-x) x}+4(x+2)\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\right) } { (x-4)^2 \sqrt{(4-x) x}}=f(x)$$ which can also write
$$f(x)=\frac{6 x}{(x-4)^2}+\frac{4 (x+2) \sqrt{x} }{(4-x)^{5/2}}\,\csc
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$

If we differentiate both side with respect to $x$
$$S_2=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n^2\,x^{n} \over {2n \choose n}}=x\,f'(x)$$
$$S_3=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n^3\,x^{n} \over {2n \choose n}}=x \big[x\,f'(x)]'$$
$$S_4=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n^4\,x^{n} \over {2n \choose n}}=x\Big[x \big[x\,f'(x)]'\Big]'$$

Making $x=2$ gives the results in the question. But, we can play with the value of $x$ and, as shown [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4274.pdf), obtain the general result

$$S_m=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n^m\,x^{n} \over {2n \choose n}}=R_{3,m}+R_{4,m}\,\,\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}\,\, \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)$$ where $R_{3,m}$ and $R_{4,m}$ are rational numbers.

Have a look [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.02.116) for the final version of the paper by
Dyson, Frankel and Glasser.

**Edit**

We could even start with
$$S_0=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{x^{n} \over {2n \choose n}}=\frac x{4-x}+\frac{4 \sqrt{x}}{(4-x)^{3/2}}\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)$$ and since
$$S_m= x S'_{m-1}$$ we can generate  similar sequence for several values of $x$ using the [particular values of the sine function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=special+values+of+sin%28x%29).

Comment: (+1) The published version of the paper mentioned in your answer may be found [here](https://doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.02.116).

Comment: Yes, that is the arXiv preprint version. For reference, it is good to have the citation info of the final, published manuscript.

Comment: @Gary. Do you think that we could do something with the chain of derivatives ?